# Providing *hint* in text field in ios 7 as edittext field in android

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitextfield, xcode5.0.1

I am creating a feedback form in an ios7 application and want to place few `UITextFields` which contain *hints* in the respective `UITextField` for name, phone number, email address, etc. I am using xcode 5 and ios7 for programming and creating application without use of storyboard.

The *hint* property is available in android for edit text field, but I am unable to find any such property in `UITextField` in ios 7.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Make use of the Placeholder text property.

Here's an example:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 50)];
textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20];
textField.placeholder = @"Your hint here.";
```

If you are using a storyboard or XIB, this property can be edited there also.

Also, if you want to use custom attributes for the placeholder, you can use the `attributedPlaceholder` property:

```
NSAttributedString *attribString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithText:@"Your hint here." attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16.0]}];
textField.attributedPlaceholder = attribString;
```

Comment: thanks for reply will check and revert back, but can you let me know whether can I apply a custom font to the placeholder ??

Comment: You going to provide an example of this or is this just a lazy answer.

Comment: Is an example required? The property can be edited just using the GUI.

Comment: I have included an example now. Was very tiring to write.

Comment: @akshag you didn't reply for usage of custom font for placeholder ?

Comment: The placeholder takes over whatever font the UITextField has. You cannot set up a custom font for UITextField.

Comment: If you want to use some other font for your placeholder, you can set the UITextField's font to the desired font and then change it in the UITextField's -textFieldDidBeginEditing: delegate method

Comment: @akashg thanks for the solution really appreciate your efforts and Thanks to Mr Popeye for telling akashg to provide example.

Comment: The reason for example is because if they knew how to do it they wouldn't be asking a question.